# Partial template specialization for specific type, c++

Tags: c++, templates, specialization, partial-specialization

Using partial specialization of templates I would like to  create a function/method:

A) processing only one specific primitive type (int, double, float,...) of the formal parameter and for other types throwing exception

```
template <class T>
T min ( Point <T> p )
{
    /*if (T == int) continue;
    else throw exception*/
}
```

B)  processing more non-primitive types (user defined types) of the formal parameter and for other types throwing exception...

Some code examples would be helpful (without c++ boost library). Thanks for your help.

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html

Comment: Throwing exceptions is a run time thing, template argument deduction is a compile time thing. Are you sure you want to do this instead of eg. triggering a compiler error ?

Comment: You can't partially specialize function templates. Only class templtaes can be partially specialized. What looks like partially specialized function templates are actually overloaded functions.

Comment: @in silico: you can go with overloads, but you can also use a template class helper: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440165/partial-specialization-of-operator/4440217#4440217

Comment: @Alexandre C.: Right. I was just being pedantic. :-)

Answer (score 7):

This is the solution of your problem (part A).

```
template<bool b> struct compile_time_assert;

template<> 
struct compile_time_assert<true> 
{};

template<class T> 
struct is_int 
{ 
     static const bool value = false; 
};
template<> 
struct is_int<int> 
{ 
     static const bool value = true; 
};

template <class T>
T min ( Point <T> p )
{
    /* 
     since you can check error at compile time, there is no reason to 
     raise exception (which is at runtime) if T is not int! 
     the following assert will not compile if T is not int.
     not only that, you can even see the error message "_error_T_is_not_int" 
     if T is not int;
    */

    compile_time_assert<is_int<T>::value> _error_T_is_not_int;

    //your code
}
```

See these sample code.

1. [sample
   code1](http://www.ideone.com/KmBaP)
   when T is int. No error. Please ignore the
   warning though!
2. [sample
   code2](http://www.ideone.com/XE4rR)
   when T is double. Now, see the error
   message also. Please ignore the
   warning though!

Similarly, you can write templates for other types, (double, char, whatever). Or, even better, you can simply merge all those into just one `struct`, and instead can define **many** booleans (for each type) in a single template, like `static const bool is_T_int = true;`. Etc. Do experiments, you'll learn!

But then, I wonder if you want your function to handle just one type, then why define template to start with?

---

For part(B), you get the idea from the above. Right? Do experiments!

Comment: @lan : I've edited my post. Please check it out. Notice, there is no need raise exception, you can catch the problem at compile time itself. I've demostrated that with two sample code also. :-)

Comment: @Navaz: Thanks... I think that compiler error is more suitable than error throwing...

Comment: @Ian : C++ template is fun. so anytime, Ian.

Answer (score 1):

you can use boost::mpl here for part B but this is use boost:(

```
#include <boost/mpl/at.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/map.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/bool.hpp>

using namespace boost;

typedef mpl::map<
    mpl::pair<int, mpl::true_>,
    mpl::pair<double, mpl::false_>,
    mpl::pair<float, mpl::false_>
> TAllowedTypesForMin;

template <class T>
T min (T p)
{
    const bool allowed = mpl::at<TAllowedTypesForMin, T>::type::value;
    if (allowed)
    {

    }

    return p;
}
```

**EDIT**

with compile time check everything is simpler:

```
#include <boost/mpl/set.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/assert.hpp>

using namespace boost;

template<class T> struct Point {};
typedef mpl::set<int, double, float> TAllowedTypesForMin;

template <class T>
T min (Point<T> p)
{
    typedef mpl::has_key<TAllowedTypesForMin, T> allowedType;
    BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_MSG( allowedType::value, NOT_SUPPORTED_TYPE, () );

// do something

    return T();
}

int main() 
{
        min(Point<long>());
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment by Alexender C., are you sure a compile error wouldn't be more suitable?

```
template <typename T> struct GateKeeper;

// Func we want to call
template <typename S, typename T> void foo (T t);

// Warpper that checks the type and forwards the call
template <typename T> inline void foo (T t)
{
  //
  // This call will fail for unless a specialization of
  // GateKeeper for `T` is defined with a member TYPE
  foo< typename GateKeeper<T>::TYPE, T > ( t );
}

//
// This declaration "allows" the type int.
template <> struct GateKeeper<int> { typedef int TYPE; };

void bar ()
{
  foo (0);   // Compiles
  foo (0.0); // Causes error in wrapping foo
}
```

A partial specialization can be used to allow any specialization of a given template:

```
// Some template type
template <typename T>
class TmplType
{
};

// This allows for specializations of TmplType
template <typename T> struct GateKeeper< TmplType<T> > { typedef int TYPE; };

void bar ()
{
  TmplType<char> tt;
  foo (tt);   // Compiles
}
```

For each type that you wish to support you add a new specialization.

**UPDATE: What is happening:**

*Note:* I've changed the template parameter names from the original version to make things a bit clearer.

When the compiler sees a call to `foo(x)` the only function that it can correctly specialize is `foo<T>(T)`.  This is because it cannot deduce all the template parameters for `foo<S,T>(T)`.

The body of `foo<T>(T)` forwards the call to the real function:

```
foo< typename GateKeeper<T>::TYPE, T > ( t );
```

(ASIDE: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-to-put-the-template-and-typename-on-dependent-names/613132#613132) for description of when to use *typename*)

This is doing 2 things at once.

The first is to provide the 2 template parameters (S and T) which are required to call the other function.

The second is to use a member of `GateKeeper<T>` as this other type.  The type `GateKeeper<T>` must be complete and have that member.  It is this check that allows us to specify which types we want to allow and which we don't:

```
template <typename T> struct GateKeeper;                  // Incomplete
template <> struct GateKeeper<int> { typedef int TYPE; }; // Complete
```

As we have only provided a definition for `GateKeeper<int>` and not for `GateKeeper<double>`, the call to `foo(0)` works correctly, and `foo(0.0)` fails with a compile error.

To allow `double`, we just need to add an explicit specialization for it:

```
template <> struct GateKeeper<double> { typedef int TYPE; }; // double now works.
```

Comment: Compile error would be more suitable...  I do not understand this line: foo< typename GateKeeper<T>::TYPE, T > ( t ); There the compiler shows an error.

Comment: @Ian:  The above example expects an error on that line as a result of the call "foo(0.0)".  If you remove that it should compile.  I'll update my answer with a bit more info about what is happening.

Comment: My comment about compiler error was related to the line: foo< typename GateKeeper<T>::TYPE, T > ( t );

Comment: @Ian. The compile error is as a result of the call to "foo(0.0)".  This call is instantiating the template with 'T==double' and "GateKeeper<double>" is not complete.

Comment: BTW typename/template FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-to-put-the-template-and-typename-on-dependent-names/613132#613132